# Chemical potentials of mixture of two kinds of ideal gases vs. ideal gas separated by partition

Tags: chemical-potential

Consider the below physical situations:

(i) Closed rigid container of volume $V$ that is isolated from the rest of the universe with uniform temperature $T$ and pressure $P$ filled and mixed with two species of ideal gases 1 and 2 with particle counts $N_1$,$N_2$. The total number of particles $N=N_1+N_2$ is fixed.

(ii) Closed rigid container of volume $V$ that is isolated from the rest of the universe with uniform temperature $T$ and pressure $P$ divided into two components of equal volume 1 and 2, separated by a partition that allows particle exchange. Both components are filled with ideal gas of the same kind with particle counts in both components $N_1$,$N_2$. The total number of particles $N=N_1+N_2$ is fixed.

In both physical situations (i) and (ii), it seems like the chemical potentials of 1 and 2 are

$$\mu_1=\mu_1^\circ + k_B T\ln \left(\frac{N_1}{N}\right)$$

$$\mu_2=\mu_2^\circ + k_B T\ln \left(\frac{N_2}{N}\right)$$

Is that true?

Comment: What do you mean by "allows particle exchange" in the case 2? Are they separated or not?

Comment: @Poutnik In case ii, components 1 and 2 are separated but are allowed to exchange particles with each other.

Comment: Then state functions are functions of time.

Comment: @Poutnik Sorry, I don't understand what do you mean.

Comment: I may have misunderstood the scenario. Is composition of compartments identical?

Comment: Let's assume that compartments have the equal volume..

Comment: This is. a potentially deep if very poorly thought-out question. An ideal gas does not consider differences in the identity of molecules since they have no size, forces etc. Removing the partition between two volumes of an ideal gas will have no effect on the energy etc. since the gas laws follow the First Law and more or less ignore the kinetic theory of gases.  It becomes interesting when the Second Law and kinetic theory are involved. Maybe rethink the question. A mix of He and Xe or of N2 and CO would be interesting.

Comment: Different diffusion rates due different molecular mass and speed would lead to slight pressure difference to balance it, until composition and pressure reach equilibrium.

Comment: If I read correctly in (i) you say that particles 1 and 2 are both in volume V, and in (ii)  there are two regions of volume V/2 one with just particle 1 and the other with particle 2, then you allow them to mix so that you have the situation in part (i).  If so you know your answer.